# How can I make a task list show different tasks for different groups?

Tags: 2010, web-part, permissions, tasks

I've added a Tasks web part to the homepage of a Sharepoint 2010 site and I want it to show "My Tasks" for some groups (e.g. the employees), "All Tasks" for others (e.g. the managers), and would like it to not be visible at all for other groups. How can I accomplish this? So far I've managed to get the web part to appear on the front page, but I've not had much success getting it to show different things based on which group the current user is in.

Note: I am brand new to SharePoint administration, step-by-step instructions are best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements right all you need to do is to set up security permissions on task items for your target user groups and individual users. And please note that audiencies is not provide security restrictions - if it's important to you.

Comment: I'm lost on how to do that dynamically. The task items in question aren't even in there yet and they're created from workflows.

Comment: What kind of workflow? SharePoint Designer's or developed in Visual Studio or else?

Comment: I... think it's developed in VS? Someone else does that.

Comment: Are your workflows visible in SharePoint Designer in the workflows section?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage Target Audience for the web part. Check articles below:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-a-web-part-to-a-specific-audience-HA010168840.aspx?CTT=3

[Manage audiences (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263065.aspx)